# Install Android-x86 on USB drive

Tags: installation, usb-peripherals, android-x86

I am live booting the Asus laptop version of Android-x86 4.0 on my Acer Laptop from my USB Pendrive. Everything is working fine, however I want to install the OS on the USB drive instead of live booting it. The USB drive is 16GB in size.

I want to live boot the system and then install on the same drive without using any other drives. If possible, later on, I would want to mount some part of the USB drive as the SD Card. How can I do this?

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are asking?

Comment: and what part you are not understanding?

Comment: btw..problem resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple, far more easier than I anticipated:

1. Partition your USB drive/SDCard, into two partitions, using this [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm), which is what I used.
2. Partition layout needs to be one with 1GB of space with FAT32 filesystem, that is for the installer.
3. Remaining partition of type ext3 (Linux partition).

The installer, when live-booting from the USB Drive/SDCard, will show the just-created partition on the USB/SDCard, just select that partition to install on it and its done.